# Left and Center align both in the same class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make **Matter**  in the HTML to be `left align` and **Index** to be center align, do I have to write another CSS class and apply to index or there is a way to manage this in the same `page-title` class

```css
.page-title {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
  line-height: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b1b7ca;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-title">Matter Index</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to have two elements as you cannot do this with a single element (barring CSS pseudo-elements).

Comment: Yeah, I think they need to be in separate elements within `.page-title` - afaik that's not possible on it's own - I'd be amazed if it was!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can do it with a little trick like this:

- Include `:after` and `:before` elements to use `text-align:justify` and separate the words like "three" columns.

  <sub>Note:You need to add a blank space at the begin of your text</sub>
- Use `direction` to get the second word aligned to the center

```css
.page-title {
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
  line-height: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b1b7ca;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  direction:rtl;
}

.page-title:before,
.page-title:after {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
}
.page-title:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-title"> Matter Index</div>
```

Comment: This is causing an extra blank line (space) under the text. Technically the last line of a paragraph is never justified (if there is only one line, it is the last line hence not justified). You basically added another line to the paragraph so the visible text is justified but the invisible extra line (space) is not.

Comment: @NawedKhan well you have to pay some price when you pact with the devil XD .... That extra space now we need to solve it

Comment: Like @NawedKhan explain the trick is justify the text, on justified text the lines dsitrbute the words along the width of the container except the last one, so we create an extra element at the end with :after to "fake" the last line now our two words will take all the width, but we need like "three" words to make three columns that's why you also use :before.

Comment: if there are ever more than 2 words then it will place 2nd and 3rd word in very weird places. Just a concern. But true, if we do not want to introduce additional containers then this is indeed the only solution/trick  :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you have to separate them. Below you will see that Matter is in separatae span and is floating left. Index is in parent Div and aligned center.

```
.page-title {
  float: left;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
  line-height: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b1b7ca;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.page-title span {float:left;}

<div class="page-title"><span>Matter</span>Index</div>
```